# What is the name of the mudra which is used in upasthaanam portion of maadhyanika sandhyavandhanam?

Tags: vedas, rituals, practice

While performing [Sandhyavandanam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhyavandanam) during noon, a particular [mudra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudra) is used in the upasthaanam part to see the sun.  An exhaustive list of mudras are given at [MudraGuide.com](http://mudraguide.com/index.php/mudras/other-mudras) but it does not cover the one I am asking about.

Shamelessly I took this image from Google search:
[image]

What is the name of that [mudra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudra)?

Comment: I believe it represents the solar system and nine planets revolving the sun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages 7-8 of [this PDF](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51b952f8e4b0326fb7d42d55/t/51ba693fe4b09da04a431e3d/1371171135432/Sandhyavandhanam+-+Jun+13%2C+2013%2C+9-33+AM.pdf) call it the "Galini mudra", while [this webpage](http://www.samskaaram.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=34:vadakalai&catid=3&lang=en) and page 19 of [this PDF](http://acharya.org/kr/sandhyavandanam/SrivaishnavaSandhyavandanam-eng.pdf) call it the "Vyoma mudra".  But in all cases the mudra depicted is the same:

[image]

Regardless of what you call it, I think the purpose of this Mudra is to get as clear a sight as possible of Surya the sun god, who is a Pratyaksha devata or visible deity, without risking blinding yourself.